How to process location data efficently?
I'm fairly new to Python (and development in general) and I've been given a project to get JSON data, that is given to us by a 3rd party (no control), imported into our system.  I'm struggling with an effective way to parse the data / work out the logic.  The data is address based, for stops, given as an [N] number of 'legs'.  With each leg being a start and end location with time.  (An example below.)  To import the data, I have to define how the trip looks.  (One-way, round trip, stops, etc.)
Here an example. (As an array of dictionary objects.)
leg[0] = { 
   'Origin' : 'location1', 
   'StartTime' : '12:00',
   'Destination' : 'location2',
   'EndTime' : '2:00'
}
leg[1] = {
   'Origin' : 'location2', 
   'StartTime' : '4:00',
   'Destination' : 'location1',
   'EndTime' : '6:00'
}
  

In that example, I gave 2 legs.  If I was given the first one, it would be a one-way trip and that's pretty easy.  Given that exact example, it's a round trip - out and back essentially.
I could also have it like this:
leg[0] = { 
   'Origin' : 'location1', 
   'StartTime' : '12:00',
   'Destination' : 'location2',
   'EndTime' : '2:00'
}
leg[1] = {
   'Origin' : 'location2', 
   'StartTime' : '4:00',
   'Destination' : 'location3',
   'EndTime' : '6:00'
}
leg[2] = { 
   'Origin' : 'location3', 
   'StartTime' : '12:00',
   'Destination' : 'location1',
   'EndTime' : '2:00'
}
  

That's where things start to get messy for me.  All I can come up with is a bunch of if/then statements trying to compare the Origin/Destination from the legs to figure out what kind of trip it is.  From the source data, it seems like 2 and 4 leg trips are the most common but I can't just assume a 4 leg trip is a round trip.  It could be one way or it could be an "unbalanced" round trip, having multiple stops before the last being the origin.
I've seen some other posts that have dealt with similar kind of requests but they just needed the data removed.  I have to keep all the data, determine what kind of of trip it is, then feed the data in correctly.  I tried to look at windowing but I couldn't find a good way to use that.  Especially since the location will read like "123 E Main Cross".  I know I could get through it with a combination of match and if/then statements but I'm hoping there is a better way that I've not been able to build the right search query to find.

With the data you've shown us here, it looks like you have a round trip if leg[-1].Destination == leg[0].Origin, and otherwise you don't have a round trip. That seems relatively straightforward.

What's the difference between a "round trip" and an "unbalanced round trip"?  Is it not sufficient just to ask the question, "did we end where we began?"

Unfortunately, no.  If a trip has an equal number of stops each direction the "end" is in the middle of the data.  If not, it's the farthest out point from the start which could be any number of the legs.  In the example data I was given, one trip had 14 legs.
It's one of those cases where a person can look at the data and quickly say, oh I know what they're doing but it's much more difficult to build a set of rules around it programmatically.

To clarify further, a balanced round trip has a start, end, and a number of stops in each direction.   Say, you start in A go to B, then C.  You wait at C a while, then go back to B, then A.    That would show as 4 legs - trip from A to C with a stop at B.    -- Unbalanced would look like, Start at A -> B -> C-> D -> end at A. - This would also be a 4 leg trip but D would be the end this time with 2 stops.

It sounds like you might want to look at something like NetworkX as it can be used to model and optimize transportation systems, such as road networks, public transit, and logistics. Applications include finding the shortest path between locations, identifying critical infrastructure, and optimizing transportation routes.

I took the suggestion by ukBaz and tried NetworkX.  It ended up working beautifully for my use case.  I built a directed graph of the data, with the stops as nodes and pairs of stops as edges.  After the graph was built, the diameter of the graph always gave me the right number for my use case. (I tested against multiple iterations of test data.
Here's some of the sample code I used:
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

legs1 = [("123 Main Street","456 oak street"),
         ("456 oak street","1000 boring ave"),
         ("1000 boring ave","123 Main Street")]

G1 = nx.DiGraph()
for leg in legs1:
    G1.add_node(leg[0])
    G1.add_node(leg[1])
    G1.add_edge(leg[0],leg[1])

print("G1 diameter:",nx.diameter(G1))
nx.draw(G1,font_size=10,with_labels=True)
plt.show()

